# Issues with "dotnet publish" and StyleCop.MSBuild in ASP.Net core

Tags: .net, publish, stylecop

We use "dotnet publish" to successfully publish a ASP.Net core application.  When we added in StyleCop to the solution however, specifically the NuGet StyleCop.MSBuild we now get the following error:

error MSB4062: The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly...

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: netcoreapp2.0 + StyleCop.MSBuild 5.0.0 with "dotnet build" we have the same issue.

Comment: there is an issue reported on github: https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/126